# Grounding a subpanel box in the same dwelling

Tags: electrical-panel

Do I have to run a seperate ground to the ground rod from the subpanel

Answer (score 6):

A sub-panel connects to the main panel with 4 conductors (hot,hot,neutral,ground).  A sub panel must have separate ground and neutral bars. A sub panel does not connect directly to the ground rod.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 2):

No, you feed the second panel with a 4 wire feeder (hot, hot, neutral, ground), and keep the neutral and ground bars separate in the second panel. The grounding conductor is connected to the grounding electrode through the main panel.